# bootstrap.widgets.TbDetailView, Yii app

Tags: yii, yii-booster

Model--

```
enter code here
 public function searchShop()
{
        $criteria = new CDbCriteria();
            $criteria->compare("name", $this->category, TRUE, "OR");
                $criteria->compare("shopname", $this->category, TRUE, "OR");
                    $criteria->compare("category", $this->category, TRUE, "OR");

            return Shops::model()->findAll($criteria);  
}
```

code----

```
enter code here
<?php 
foreach($models as $model):
    $this->widget(
'bootstrap.widgets.TbDetailView',
array(
'type'=>'bordered condensed',
'data' => array(
'id' =>array('view', 'id'=>$model->ID),
'Shop Name' => $model->shopname,
'Category' => $model->category,
'ID' => CHtml::link(CHtml::encode($model->ID), array('view', 'id'=>$model->ID))
),
'attributes' => array(
array('name' => 'Shop Name', 'label' => 'Shop name'),
array('name' => 'Category', 'label' => 'Category'),
array('name' => 'ID', 'label' => 'ID'),
),
)
);

echo "<br><hr><br>";
 endforeach;
 ?>
```

---

I want a link on ID by clicking on it it will render view file i.e view.php of shops model

I used CHtml::link(CHtml::encode($model->ID), array('view', 'id'=>$model->ID)) but it is showing path of that view as [1](/myapp/index.php/shops/1)

help me...
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
 CHtml::link(CHtml::encode($model->ID),
CController::createUrl('site/view',array('id'=>$model->ID)))
```

here i have assumed that action view lies in site controller. If it lies under some other module name then you can write like this `"moduleName/controllerName/actionName"`

**Edit:**
Ok you have to try a few things. TbDetailView extends CDetatilView. Now you can use TbDetailView as

```
$this->widget(
'bootstrap.widgets.TbDetailView',
array(
'type'=>'bordered condensed',
'data' => array(
'id' =>array('view', 'id'=>$model->ID),
'Shop Name' => $model->shopname,
'Category' => $model->category,
),
'attributes' => array(
array('name' => 'Shop Name', 'label' => 'Shop name'),
array('name' => 'Category', 'label' => 'Category'),
array('label' => 'ID', 'value' => CHtml::link(CHtml::encode($model->ID), array('view', 'id'=>$model->ID))),
),
)
);
```

You can also do like

```
 $this->widget(
'bootstrap.widgets.TbDetailView',
array(
'type'=>'bordered condensed',
'data' =>$model,
'attributes' => array(
array('name' => 'shopname', 'label' => 'Shop name'),
array('name' => 'category', 'label' => 'Category'),
array('value' =>  CHtml::link(CHtml::encode($model->ID), array('view', 'id'=>$model->ID))
),, 'label' => 'ID'),
),
)
)
```

;

Comment: I did the same.. 'ID' => CHtml::link(CHtml::encode($model->ID),
CController::createUrl('shops/view',array('id'=>$model->ID)))  Its not working

Comment: not working? is the link being showing correctly? is it clickable? what is it showing?

Comment: Link is correct but not clickable... showing link for that ID.. i am using URL manager... is it wrong to use URL manager???

Comment: No if it is not clickable then it is not an issue of URL manager. Please correct me if i am wrong. It only shows you 1? Means $model->id is so it only shows you 1 but not clickable?

Comment: CHtml::link(CHtml::encode($model->ID),
    CController::createUrl('site/view',array('id'=>$model->ID)))                  shows url string instead of showing ID having link to view.php page...      it shows url address as <a href="/myapp/index.php?r=shops/view&amp;id=1">1</a>

Comment: please see edits if it helps. If one solution does not work then try the other one also

Comment: thanks for the help... i did it.. only change is..    'ID' => CHtml::link(CHtml::encode($model->ID), array('shops/view', 'id'=>$model->ID)),
         CHtml::link(CHtml::encode($model->city->name),array('city/view','id'=>$model->city->id)),
    'Shop Name' =>CHtml::link(CHtml::encode($model->shopname),array('shops/view','id'=> $model->ID)),
    'Category' => $model->category
    ),
    'attributes' => array(
 
  array('name' => 'ID','label' => 'ID','value'=>CHtml::link(CHtml::encode($model->ID), 
     array('shops/view', 'id'=>$model->ID)),'type'=>'raw'),